# Making a heap copy of a struct in D

Tags: garbage-collection, stack, immutability, d

How can I create a garbage-collected copy of a struct that's on the stack?

Coming from a C++ background, my first guess would be a copy constructor like the one below, but it doesn't seem very idiomatic for D, and I haven't seen one in any of the D projects I've taken a look at.

```
struct Foo {
    immutable int bar;

    this(int b) { bar = b; }

    // A C++-style copy constructor works but doesn't seem idiomatic.
    this(ref const Foo f) { bar = f.bar; }
}

void main()
{
    // We initialize a Foo on the stack
    auto f = Foo(42);

    // Now I want to get a heap copy of its member. How?

    // A C++-style copy constructor works but doesn't seem idiomatic.
    Foo* f1 = new Foo(f);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example is overly complicated and doesn't even compile, but essentially, it sounds like what you want to be able to do is something like

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;
}

void main()
{
    auto f = Foo(5);
    auto g = new Foo(f);
}
```

What you can do without any special constructors is

```
void main()
{
    auto f = Foo(5);
    auto g = new Foo;
    *g = f;
}
```

but obviously that's more steps than you probably want. The normal "copy constructor" for D is a postblit constructor, which is declared as [`this(this) {...}`](http://dlang.org/struct.html#StructPostblit), but that's not required for `Foo` as it's declared here (since all of its members are value types), and it doesn't help with allocating a struct on the heap anyway - just with copying a struct. Arguably

```
auto f = Foo(5);
auto g = new Foo(f);
```

should just work, but at the moment, it doesn't, and there is unfortunately, no support in the language for defining it for you. So, unfortunately, I think that you're currently forced to do something akin to what you're trying to avoid. e.g.

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;

    this(int j)
    {
        i = j;
    }

    this(Foo rhs)
    {
        this = rhs;
    }
}

void main()
{
    auto f = Foo(5);
    auto g = new Foo(f);
}
```

However, I just opened [an enhancement request](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12918) for making it so that `new Foo(foo)` will just work, and with the next release of dmd (2.066) we're going to get universal construction for primitive types (e.g. `new int(5)` will now work), so I think that there's a very good argument for this just working as well.

For now though, you're going to have to provide an extra constructor to get this to work.

Comment: Sometimes I wish I can +10 some of your answers here! :)

Comment: Crap. Sorry for the broken example; this is what happens when I post to SO at 1 AM before going to bed. I originally had a more complicated example, pared it down, and then forgot to remove the second struct from the rest of the example. Thanks for the excellent job of predicting what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`[s].ptr` will copy the struct `s` to the heap, and get a pointer to it.

Comment: I forgot about that trick. Thanks for pointing it out. However, the downside to it is that it's going to allocate more memory than simply allocating a new struct on the heap would, since druntime allocates extra memory for arrays for additional capacity and for bookkeeping. So, it's nice and terse, but it does carry extra cost.