# Immutability in D constructors

Tags: constructor, d, immutability, copy-constructor

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216231/making-a-heap-copy-of-a-struct-in-d) discussed making a copy constructor like so:

```
struct Foo {
    int i;

    this(int j) { i = j; }

    this(Foo rhs) { this = rhs; }
}

void main()
{
    auto f = Foo(5);
    auto g = new Foo(f);
}
```

But, if I make `i` immutable, the constructor fails to compile with

> Error: cannot modify struct this Foo with immutable members

Why is this the case? I was under the impression that immutable members of a class or struct do not become immutable until the end of the constructor is reached.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay. In general, I'd advise against having structs with `immutable` members. There are just too many places where it's useful to be able to assign to one. What you typically want to do with a struct is make it so that it can be mutable, `const`, or `immutable` as a whole. And for the most part, that just works. e.g.

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;

    this(int j) { i = j; }

    this(Foo rhs) { this = rhs; }
}

void main()
{
    immutable f = Foo(5);
}
```

compiles just fine. The one area that generally causes trouble with that is when you have to have a postblit constructor, because those don't currently work with `const` or `immutable` structs (it's something that sorely needs to be fixed, but it's still an open problem due to how the type system works - it may result in us having to add copy constructors to the language, or we may figure out how to do it, but for now, it doesn't work, and it can be annoying). But that only affects you if you need a postblit constructor, which most structs don't need (the problem will be fixed eventually though, because it really needs to be; it's just a question of how and when).

However, to answer your question more generally, let's look at a class. For instance, this code won't compile, because the constructor is not `immutable`, and the compiler can't convert an `immutable` class object to a mutable one (it can do that with structs, because it makes a copy, but with a class, it's just copying the reference, not the object, so it doesn't work):

```
class Foo
{
    int i;

    this(int j) { i = j; }
}

void main()
{
    auto f = new immutable Foo(5);
}
```

Instead of that compiling, you get this lovely error message:

```
q.d(10): Error: mutable method q.Foo.this is not callable using a immutable object
q.d(10): Error: no constructor for Foo
```

There are three ways to solve this. The first is to make the constructor `immutable`

```
class Foo
{
    int i;

    this(int j) immutable { i = j; }
}
```

and that works, but it makes it so that you can *only* construct `Foo`s which are `immutable`, which usually isn't what you want (though it sometimes is). So, the second way to solve the problem would be to take the first solution a step further and overload the constructor. e.g.

```
class Foo
{
    int i;

    this(int j) { i = j; }

    this(int j) immutable { i = j; }
}
```

However, that requires code duplication, which isn't a lot here, but it could be a lot for other types. So, what is generally the *best* solution is to make the constructor `pure`.

```
class Foo
{
    int i;

    this(int j) pure { i = j; }
}
```

This works, because the compiler then knows that nothing has escaped the constructor (since `pure` guarantees that nothing escapes by being assigned to a global or static variable, and the constructor's parameters don't allow anything to escape either), and because it knows that no references to `Foo` or its members can escape the constructor, it knows that there are no other references to this `Foo` and that it therefore can safely convert it to mutable, `const`, or `immutable` without violating the type system. Of course, that only works if you *can* make the constructor `pure` and nothing can escape via the constructor's arguments, but that's *usually* the case, and when it isn't, you can always just overload the constructor on mutability, much as that's less desirable.

The same techniques can be used on structs if you really want `const` or `immutable` members, but again, I'd advise against it. It's just going to cause you more trouble than it's worth, especially when it's usually trivial to just make the whole struct `const` or `immutable` when declaring a variable.

Comment: Thank you again for your time! This is an excellent and thorough answer. Sorry if the question is a bit odd - I'm picking up D after spending lots of time in C++. While D simplifies in a lot of places, I'm just trying to figure out what idioms work well in D and which don't really belong.

Answer (score 2):

Making members of structs `immutable` stops assigning to the struct which in turn causes quite a few issues, you may which to rethink that.

Otherwise assign the members directly instead of relying on the assignment operator:

```
struct Foo {
    immutable int i;

    this(int j) { i = j; }

    this(in Foo rhs) { this.i = rhs.i; }
}
```

Comment: Would you consider immutable members to be an antipattern or something to avoid? It's something I've used extensively in the past in C++ to make objects immutable, but it certainly does have drawbacks.

Comment: The problem is that it prevents `opAssign` from working which is a pain to say the least

Comment: `immutable` members in classes isn't generally a big deal, because they're reference types, but with structs, it can be very annoying, because there are just too many places where you end up wanting to assign to one. It's generally better to have a struct which does not have `immutable` members but which can be `immutable` when you want it to be.